# Efficient copy memory

Tags: c

I inherited the following code:

```
void *buf1 = calloc(1,total_buf_size);
//build buf1 up with memcpy 
int index;
void *buf2 = buf1;

for (index = 0; index < log->numentries; index++)
{
  logentry_t *entry = (logentry_t*)&log->entries[index];

  memcpy(buf2,entry->entryname,sizeof(entry->entryname));
  buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->entryname);
  memcpy(buf2,&entry->entrysize,sizeof(entry->entrysize));
  buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->entrysize);
  memcpy(buf2,&entry->updatesize,sizeof(entry->updatesize));
  buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->updatesize);
  memcpy(buf2,&entry->numupdates,sizeof(entry->numupdates));
  buf2  = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->numupdates);

  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < entry->numupdates; j++)
  {   
    memcpy(buf2,&entry->offsets[j],sizeof(entry->offsets[j]));
    buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->offsets[j]);
  }

  int k;
  for (k = 0; k < entry->numupdates; k++)
  {
    memcpy(buf2,&entry->sizes[k],sizeof(entry->sizes[k]));
    buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->sizes[k]);      
  }


  memcpy(buf2,entry->data,entry->updatesize);
}
```

I have a transaction log that I'm iterating through and need to write the data for each log entry to a row in a file.  Currently it's using memcpy to build a buffer of all the entries and writes them all at once to the file.  Is there a better way to copy and expand memory into buf2?

Comment: Is it text? You could `fprintf` a line for each log entry?

Comment: entry->data is a void, so I can't guarantee it will be a string, although in this instance, I think that will work.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think any sort of copying is efficient enough for on-disk logging. If you're talking about code readability, then there is some room for improvements. Also, even if it is not text (and it seems to not be), you may not collect the buffer yourself but let `fwrite()` do buffering job for you.

Comment: I saw there is `entry->entryname`. The other `struct` fields can be output as text with `fprintf(..."%d",...)`, for example? And a `NULL` pointer can be printed as "void" or "null" etc.

Comment: This code does arithmetic on a `void*`, which is undefined behaviour I believe.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to c.  Can you elaborate on the "arithmetic on a void*" comment?  Thanks

Comment: You might, might, get better performance if you setup a structure that emulates the incoming data and one for the outgoing data.  Then you could just assign the values into memory using = instead of memcpy, though there is no guarentee that the compiler won't use memcpy behind the scenes.  This does give the compiler more options to help you out though.  Better, if the same structure is used for both in and out going data, then you can just assign the whole structure.

Comment: You have `void *buf2 = buf1;`. Then you do `buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->entryname);`. The `buf2 + x`-part is undefined. `void` has no size, so you can't say: "Give me the address of the n-th `void`-thing in this array/pointer".

Comment: @EOF It is well-known and widely implemented gcc extension in that pointer arithmetic on void* is treated as if it was char*. But it would be more correct to declare buffers as char* and always compile with -std=whatever -Wall -Werror or even -pedantic.

Comment: @user3125367: I am aware of it, and consider it to be insane.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of efficiency your looking for but here is an example of writing each log entry record out to the file and then resetting the buffer buf2 for each iteration. You can thus reduce the buf1 size (defined by total_buf_size) to something that will fit just one log entry record:

```
void *buf1 = calloc(1,total_buf_size);
//With this method total_buf_size can be reduced to fit just one log entry record

//build buf1 up with memcpy 
int index;
void *buf2 = buf1;

FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");

for (index = 0; index < log->numentries; index++)
{
  logentry_t *entry = (logentry_t*)&log->entries[index];

  memcpy(buf2,entry->entryname,sizeof(entry->entryname));
  buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->entryname);
  memcpy(buf2,&entry->entrysize,sizeof(entry->entrysize));
  buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->entrysize);
  memcpy(buf2,&entry->updatesize,sizeof(entry->updatesize));
  buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->updatesize);
  memcpy(buf2,&entry->numupdates,sizeof(entry->numupdates));
  buf2  = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->numupdates);

  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < entry->numupdates; j++)
  {   
    memcpy(buf2,&entry->offsets[j],sizeof(entry->offsets[j]));
    buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->offsets[j]);
  }

  int k;
  for (k = 0; k < entry->numupdates; k++)
  {
    memcpy(buf2,&entry->sizes[k],sizeof(entry->sizes[k]));
    buf2 = buf2 + (int)sizeof(entry->sizes[k]);      
  }


  memcpy(buf2,entry->data,entry->updatesize);

  fwrite(buf2, sizeof(logentry_t), sizeof(buf2), pFile);

  memset(&buf2, 0, sizeof(buf2)); //clear it out
  buf2 = buf1; //reset the pointer
}

fclose(pFile);
free(buf2);
```

Comment: Any time you inject disk I/O into a memory operation, you have just slowed it down by orders of magnitude. That may very well have been the reason for collecting the buffer in memory and preforming a single write to begin with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OTOH stdio's BUFSIZ is meant to be well-tuned and syscall penalty should be minor when performed only once per BUFSIZ number of bytes. You *have* to `write` them at some time anyway and if it's not syscall-per-byte, you're fine. If OP wanted to do that really fast, he should consider using sort of asynchronous io queue instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment below the question I meant something like:

```
FILE *file = fopen("log.file", "a"); // assert(file != NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < log->numentries, i++) {
    logentry_t *e = (logentry_t*)&log->entries[i];

#define OUT(x) do { fwrite(x, sizeof(x), 1, file) } while (0)
    OUT(e->entryname);
    OUT(e->entrysize);
    OUT(e->updatesize);
    OUT(e->numupdates);

    for (int j = 0; j < e->numupdates; j++)
        OUT(&e->offsets[j]);

    for (int k = 0; k < e->numupdates; k++)
        OUT(&entry->sizes[k]);

    fwrite(e->data, e->updatesize, 1, file);
#undef OUT
}
fflush(file);

...
```

I.e. you don't need bufs at all because `fwrite` already performs buffering at `stdio.h` layer. This code was not tested and may contain errors of any kind.

Also note that writing raw data into log file may lead to little/big endian and integer size issues on different platforms or even compilers (though the latter is less probable, depending on actual types of logentry_t fields). You may consider preformatting integer data fields to portable fixed-size representation via something like `htons`/`htonl` or even `printf("%ld", (long)x)` them as text.